# Why isn't this text showing up on my phone?

Tags: python, function, text, smtp

Here is the link to the original post: [Why am I not able to send a Colon in a message but am able to send a Semicolon??? (Python, SMTP module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776061/why-am-i-not-able-to-send-a-colon-in-a-message-but-am-able-to-send-a-semicolon/25776278#25776278to) a

It's something to do with the colon in the time.  I tried formatting it different ways, and the colon in the time makes the text show up on my phone blank.  Here is a simple version of the texting function I am using.  It is SMTP to a Verizon iPhone, if that makes a difference.  I could use a semicolon and it'd work, but a colon doesn't:

```
import time
current = (str(time.strftime("%I:%M %p")))

print (current)

def Text():
    import smtplib
    ContentMatch = ("Content match, website checked at: ", current)
    username = ("EmailUser")
    password = ("Password1")
    fromaddr = ("Username@gmail.com")
    toaddrs  = ("PhoneNumber@vtext.com")
    message = (str(ContentMatch))
    # The actual mail send
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, message)
    server.quit()

Text()
```

Comment: @paxdiablo no I deleted to original. This is a simpler version as the other one couldn't be answered

Comment: Apologies, Preston, at the time I looked, the original was still there and it looked like this was just some extra info that would have been better added to that original. I've undeleted this one, sorry for the trouble. You may want to add some of the original info to this one since the link you've given above is only visible to a certain level of rep.

Answer (score 0):

Your message is not correctly formatted. The message string must be an RFC2822-compatible message. That is, it must include a header and an optional body.

Try this:

```
message = "From: %s\n\n%s\n"%(fromaddr, ContentMatch)
```

But Python provides special classes (e.g. [email.mime.text.MIMEText](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText)) for formatting email messages, so you don't have to do it by hand:

```
import time
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate

current = time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
message_text = "Content match, website checked at: %s" % current


def Text():
    # Parameters for sending
    username = "xxx"
    password = "xxx"
    fromaddr = "xxx@example.com"
    toaddr = "xxx@example.com"

    # Create the message. The only RFC2822-required headers
    # are 'Date' and 'From', but adding 'To' is polite
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['Date'] = formatdate()
    message['From'] = fromaddr

    # Send the message
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, message.as_string())
    server.quit()

Text()
```